# Courier New font for specification

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I can't embed a copy of Courier New True Type fonts in my website due to Microsoft license, so my website only uses Courier New for code sections where the host system has Courier New installed. Is there a font that is very close to Courier New?

The obvious categories of Courier New:

- Monospace
- Serif?

This is not a duplicate question of the following because I'm not needing full Unicode support.

[Courier New-like font with Unicode support?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/courier-new-like-font-with-unicode-support)

Comment: Courier New is Monotype, not Microsoft. It's also included in most modern operating systems. I'm no expert, but why would you need to embed it when it's already available?

Comment: @Tetsujin I was wondering if most Linux and an Apple OS all support Courier New.

Comment: it's in macOS by default, idk about nix flavours

Comment: It's also in Windows 11 by default.  @Hydroper - what about using Courier Prime from Google Fonts?

Answer (score 2):

Courrier and Courrier New are a web-safe fonts, which means that it is installed on almost every computer.

No need to download a similar one.

Add the generic monospaced, for the rare cases they have not.

Answer (score 1):

Courier Prime is based on Courier and is open-source.